# My, code has an Unexpected Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, token

I need help my JavaScript is broken apparently!

```
var orangeCost = function(price); {
     var price =  * 5;
     console.log(price); 
}; 

orangeCost(5)
```

***Update:***

In the FireFox Console the Error is:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'
```

In the Chrome Console the Error is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Comment: paste that code into an online linter service .... will tell you exactly where the problem(s) are. Dumb syntax errors shouldn't become questions here when there are readily  available  tools to figure them out

Comment: The problem is entirely obvious... Why is there an extra semicolon on the first line? Also, the way in which you are attempting to multiply the price is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon in function definition. I believe you are trying to multiply the price value by 5 and displaying it. So you should have the `price` variable in front of `*` operator.

```
var orangeCost = function(price) {
     price = price * 5;
     console.log(price); 
}; 

orangeCost(5)
```

Comment: Hey I tried that but it didn't work. My goal is to get console.log() to print the amount it will cost for 5 oranges if each orange cost 5 dollars

Comment: @JamesSingewald Just copy paste my code in jsfiddle or in your browser  it should work. I just tested it and worked. (Displayed 25)

Comment: get rid of the `var`, makes no sense.

Comment: `price *= 5;` would also work which may have been what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: @Andy Tried in my Chrome, the console error was `Unexpected token *=`

Comment: @DhiwaTdG, worked in FF. Didn't try chrome.

Comment: @DhiwaTdG, works in Chrome for me...